# Show HTML in flash

Tags: flash, webkit

You can build apps in HTML using Adobe AIR which parses it using Webkit, can this be done in Flash?

For example you have a string that contains `<html><body><b>hello world</b></body></html>` and then call a function that runs the WebKit parser over it and then outputs 'hello world' in bold to the stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope...that works just in AIR.

Closest thing you've got is this [HTMLWrapper library](http://code.google.com/p/htmlwrapper/) as far as I know. Not the same thing,
but could be handy.

Answer (score 1):

Using the htmlText property of a multiline TextField object could be a substitute, although very limited. (You can use text formatting tags like `<b>`, lists, `<p>`, `<span>`, `<img>` and I guess that's about it.)